# Not Getting Correct Answers When Reading the OMR Sheet Answers using the API

Tags: python, omr

When I am Reading the OMR Sheet Answers using the API, the Selected Answers are showing wrong and not Getting the Response in JSON Format

the API using, provided by,
https://products.aspose.cloud/omr/python

Here I am Using Python Code provided by the API provider.
**Answers Returning like:**

```
Questions1:ABC
Questions2:BC
Questions3:BCD
Questions4:AB
Questions5:BCD
Questions6:ABCD
Questions7:BC
Questions8:ABD
Questions9:ABC
```

Which is Wrong Answers.